# using System.currentTimeMillis() as primary key in the hibernate table

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

iam working on application where i want to use a unique non-null number as primary key in the table. I dont want to use auto-generated value in this application.

Hence iam using System.currentTimeMillis(); as primary key..
Is it the right approach???

the code looks  something like this

```
FileData fileData = new FileData();
    Long seqnum = System.currentTimeMillis();
fileData.setSeqnum(seqnum);
. setting other fields
.
.
fileRepository.save(fileData);
```

My fear is if i deploy the code on server it is quite possible that at the same time two request may come to server and the two threads created by server for request may get same `seqnum`.

Can somebody suggest me if my approach is correct or not? 
If it is not correct then please suggest an alternative way?

Comment: No, it's not. Use a sequence, or a UUID. *I dont want to use auto-generated value in this application.*: and how is using currentTimeMillis() different, except that it's unsafe?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_nextval_function.htm  will this link solve my problem??

Comment: No. Read the Hibernate/JPA documentation for how to configure an auto-generated ID based on a sequence. Dont reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I have used the auto-generated id in other modules of project..But here i want to use auto-generated id further in my code....so how will i get hold of this auto-generated id..Hibernate will automatically generate the id and save the record. but i want to get hold of the primary key..how is it possible>

Comment: You save the entity, and voilà. The ID is generated. So you get it using savedEntty.getId().